# Extjs4 and IE8 : beforeclose event on a tab throw an 'cannot execute code from freed script'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, extjs4

I have a problem that make me crazy with extjs4 and IE8 with the tab panel.

I must refresh a specific tab when I close another tab to take care of the modifications. I use the 'beforeclose' event to trigger the refresh. On FF it's ok. But with IE8 (the target of my application), I have a 'cannot execute code from freed script'.

Can someby help me ?

Here is the code :

```
var activeTab = getTabPanel().getActiveTab(); // getTabPanel() give me the tab panel
activeTab.on('beforeclose', function(tab, opts) {
    alert("refresh !!!!");
    tab.refreshTab('order_'+id); // refreshTab(id) search the tab with the id identifier and refresh the contents
}
```

The alert is not displayed, so I supposed that the listener cannot be processed.

EDIT : I use iframes as contents of the tab panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found where is the bug.

This code attach a listener on the beforeclose event, and the listener is called by the parent window. If I refresh the iframe (via submitting a form or using the 'refresh' action), the event is still attached to the parent window BUT the callback function has disappeared from the memory.
With Firefox, the callback is successfully called twice, but IE throw a "can't execute code from a freed script" error.

For solving this, I attach a call on the beforeunload event to detach the listener.